# Sieving asymptotics

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $S(k, n)$ be the set of numbers not exceeding $n$ whose prime factors are among the first $k$ primes. The question is: what is the asymptotic behavior of the cardinality of $S(k, n).$ To be more specific, obviously as $k$ stays fixed and $n$ goes to infinity, this quantity behaves as $\log(n)^k,$ and as $n$ stays fixed and $k$ goes to infinity, it behaves like $n.$ But the question is - where are the phase transitions? What is the functional dependence of $k$ on $n$ so that $|S(k, n)|\sim n^\alpha?$ or $|S(k, n)| = c n?$

Comment: I think clarity is needed.  If you are talking about k smooth numbers n for a fixed k, their density slowly dwindles as n grows. If you are talking numbers not coprime to the kth primorial, those numbers have a positive not far from 1 density for large k fixed and large n increasing.  Gerhard "Or Is It Something Else?" Paseman, 2018.02.28.

Comment: I agree with G"..."P: you should check out the literature on friable (or smooth) numbers, and their counting function $\Psi(x,y)$. For example, the $k$ such that $\#S(k,n) \approx n^\alpha$ is a power of $\log n$, I believe $(\log n)^{1/(1-\alpha)}$.